# Алгоритм увеличения полигона на заданную величину

Tags: javascript, геометрия

Есть выпуклый полигон:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**P** - величина, на которую необходимо увеличить полигон (в мм).

**L, L1, L2, H, H1** - управляющие величины (в мм).

Есть ли универсальный алгоритм увеличения подобных полигонов?

Может есть js-библиотеки?

Comment: Судя по картинке, у вас все величины задаются целыми числами (кратно сетке). При увеличении полигона на Р, величины H, H1, L1, L2 станут некратными. Это приемлимо?

Comment: Да. Изображение делал для понимания задачи.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если у вас полигон задается точками (с координатами в 2D), то базовый алгоритм:

- находим центр полигона (тут нам помогает то, что он всегда выпуклый, по условию)
- перебираем все отрезки сторон и смещаем их точки "наружу" на `Р` (т.е. считаем 2 нормали к стороне (у вас - всегда 90 градусов, т.е. просто меняем оси) и выбираем ту что смотрит от центра)
- смещение наружу считаем как противоположное от направления к центру и двигаем по нормали к отрезку
- после смещения, для всех соседних отрезков ищем новые точки пересечения (продолжаем прямые)

По окончании, можете восстановить свои "управляющие" величины.

Comment: @doox911 уточните, что именно вам неясно? Берете отрезок между 1-2 точками, вычисляете его нормаль (перпендикуляр). Их будет 2 штуки. Выбираете ту что смотрит в направлении ОТ центра (у которой расстояние до центра больше)

Comment: Не понятен второй вопрос. Вот на нашел центр полигона(`x: L/2, y:H/2`). Вертикальные и горизонтальные линии я смещу, а как наклонную смещать? И не совсем понятно, что вы имеете в виду, когда говорите, что у меня всегда 90 градусов?

Comment: @doox911 Вам нужно векторную алгебру вспомнить. Можем обсудить в чате https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113316/vector-algebra

Comment: @doox911 вот вспомнил что делал когда-то митер лимиты, там нечто подобное в основе https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/MWgOqRJ